# Error: net::ERR_FAILED ошибка [Puppeteer]

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Puppeteer обходит рекурсией 800 страниц, всё работает отлично, но примерно к 250 странице он начинает выдавать ошибку:

```
Error: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Утечек памяти нет, ОЗУ куча свободного. Не понимаю почему так происходит, может кто сталкивался?

Версия Puppeteer 2.0.0

Пробовал разные страницы разных сайтов, исход один.

Ещё бывает ошибка чуть другая, но суть одна:

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
0|index  | Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-tls.c: 493: _dl_allocate_tls_init: Assertion `listp->slotinfo[cnt].gen <= GL(dl_tls_generation)' failed!
```

Comment: А можно сразу попробовать открыть эти проблемные страницы, чтобы быть уверенным, что дело не в них, а в количестве запросов?

Comment: Выбивает на разных страницах, пробовал любые разных сайтов.

Comment: Старенькая у вас версия, уже 7-я с хвостиком вышла. Может, обновитесь? Вдруг за столько времени как раз вашу проблему исправили.

Comment: Вынужден был перейти на старую версию, она более менее стабильная. В 7 вообще чаще ошибки возникают.